# Hobby vs. Business

Tags: united-states, income-tax, turbotax, hobby-income

I do a small amount of tutoring. On my tax returns, I do not want to list it as a business because that makes my returns more complicated than they need to be and makes my tax prep software more expensive.

I do enjoy tutoring, and I don't rely on the income at all, but I don't think I can  honestly call it a hobby. On the other hand, it's not much of a business, earning as it does under 1.5K. It's all private, so there's no 1099, neither is their any paper trail at all.

Is there anywhere else on my return I can squeeze this money in? I use TurboTax.

Comment: Unfortunately, the income threshold is $400. So if it's more than $400 and you do it primarily to make a profit, you are probably required to report it as self-employment business income.

Answer (score 4):

"Miscellaneous income" -- same category used for hobbies.

Answer (score 3):

You can list it as **other income** reported on **line 21 of form 1040**.

In **TurboTax**, enter at:
- Federal Taxes tab (Personal in  Home & Business)
- Wages & Income
-“I’ll choose what I work on” Button
Scroll down to:
-Less Common Income
-Misc Income, 1099-A, 1099-C.
-The next screen will give you several choices. Choose "**Other reportable Income**". You will reach a screen where you can type a description of the income and the amount.

Type in the amount of income and categorize as Tutoring.